# SQL query using INNER JOIN is excluding some database records where the field value is MP

Tags: sql, jet

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT [Public Talk Titles].*, [Public Talk Categories].Description AS [Category Description]
FROM [Public Talk Categories] 
INNER JOIN [Public Talk Titles] ON [Public Talk Categories].Category = [Public Talk Titles].Category
ORDER BY [Public Talk Titles].[Talk Number];
```

It works, except, it does not like it when the value of Category is **MP**. All database rows where the category is that value are stripped from the database. I am using Microsoft Access 2016 with a MDB file.

If I change the category from MP to something else, eg XX in both the tables and run my query it works as expected and all records are displayed.

So it is something to do with this MP value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you sure the value MP is exactly the same in both tables? what if you try to use LIKE %..% instead of = for the join condition?

Comment: @AndreiXwe You are on to something. If I edit one of the fields and change it to something else and then back to MP (from the drop-down list of values) then that record shows in the query results.

Comment: then just make sure the strings are exactly the same, try to trim them before inserting

Comment: @AndreiXwe The thing is, if I export the table as a text file and locate these values they seem right to me!. Let me look.

Comment: what if you try to run an update on those columns? something like `UPDATE table SET column = 'MP' where column LIKE '%MP%'` ?

Comment: @AndreiXwe can I run this UPDATE query from the same Query Wizard? All my UPDATE statements are managed within my MFC application you see so I don't want to change that just for this.

Comment: @AndreiXwe I see the Update button on the ribbon. I will try.

Comment: @AndreiXwe In the end I just entered the value MP again from the drop-list for all records in the table. Did not take long and all is OK. Thanks.

Comment: np, then i will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the value MP is exactly the same in both tables, try trimming the strings and inserting again or run something like `UPDATE table SET column = 'MP' where column LIKE '%MP%'`